# How to install and configure MSMTP on OSX?

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra, msmtp

Following the instructions on [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/msmtp) to install and configure `msmtp` does not work. The file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` or anything like it is missing, and trying to use `msmtp` to send mail will result in a certificate error.

What is an alternate configuration for OSX High Sierra so that `msmtp` can be used to send mail like in the tutorial?

Note: I answered this question for myself some time ago and decided it's useful and worth sharing, so I created this question and answer. It would be nice if someone with more knowledge of certificates and fingerprints could provide a higher quality answer with more detail and background information about the difference between using a certificate or a fingerprint, for example.

Note years later: I know it's a self answered Q/A but this has 1k views so maybe remember to upvote a useful Q/A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative method that works for me and avoids the issue of the tls_fingerprint expiring.

Use MacPorts to install the curl CA bundle:

`sudo port install curl-ca-bundle`

Locate the bundle:

```
port contents curl-ca-bundle

Port curl-ca-bundle contains:
  /opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

Add the following line to .msmptrc

`tls_trust_file /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt`

It works:

```
Hatchet:~ me$ mail me@mac.com
Subject: Hi Mike
done
.
EOT
```

No error. From the log file:

`exitcode=EX_OK`

Comment: Confirming that this works very nicely on 10.9.5 (Mavericks), and avoids the problem of expiring tls fingerprints.

Comment: Great! Finally someone got annoyed enough by expiring fingerprints to find the proper answer :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `tls_fingerprint` field in `~/.msmtprc` instead of `tls_trust_file`. To generate the field value for `tls_fingerprint`, you can run the command

`msmtp --serverinfo --tls --tls-certcheck=off --host=smtp.gmail.com --port=587 | egrep -o "([0-9A-Za-z]{2}:){31}[0-9A-Za-z]{2}"`

`tls_fingerprint` and `tls_trust_file` are mutually exclusive, so do not try to use both, or `msmtp` will have a configuration error.

Here is a [script](https://github.com/okovko/msmtp_gmail_setup/blob/master/msmtp_setup.sh) you can run to install and configure `msmtp` for use with a `gmail` account on either `Ubuntu 18` or `Mac OSX High Sierra`.

Comment: The caveat on this method is that the tls_fingerprint expires after what seems to be a random length of time. When mail stops working you have to generate a new fingerprint. There must be a better way.